# Sql create a table based on a cell value

Tags: sql, count, populate

I have a problem where I have tables that are created based on the date & time, this table is created in a SP that I didn't write. In any event need to get a count of these tables every time they are created.

What I have done so far is create a table that has these names, and added a Count field.
Table looks like this and is called SP.DBO.AUSEMAIL

```
SourceTable                                          Count
SP.DBO.VIP_BPAU_00030_20130531_092027
SP.DBO.ADV_BPAU_00030_20130531_092027
```

Now basically I need to create a query that will give me a count of SP.DBO.VIP_BPAU_00030_20130531_092027 and SP.DBO.ADV_BPAU_00030_20130531_092027 and populate the above table.

As I will not know what the table will be called every day, and am working towards fully automating this I can't just to counts of each of these files.

I have tried something like this and am getting nowhere.

```
select count(*)
from top 1 (select sourcetable
from SP.DBO.AUSEMAIL
where source_table like 'SP.DBO.VIP_BPAU%')
```

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: "I have a problem where i have tables that are created based on the date & time" - that is rarely  a good design....That's what a date column is for!

Answer (score 0):

To update `count` column in your `ausemail` table

```
UPDATE a
   SET a.count = i.rowcnt
  FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o 
    ON i.id = o.id JOIN ausemail a
    ON o.name = a.source_table
```

If you know exactly the pattern you can do something like this

```
SELECT o.name source_table, 
       i.rowcnt count
  FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o 
    ON i.id = o.id 
 WHERE o.name LIKE '___!_BPAU!_%' ESCAPE '!' -- < adjust the pattern as needed
```

Sample output:

```
|                   SOURCE_TABLE | COUNT |
------------------------------------------
| VIP_BPAU_00030_20130531_092027 |     4 |
| ADV_BPAU_00030_20130531_092027 |     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8e5f/11)** demo.

Comment: @user2446846 I'm glad it helped :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.